Is it possible to combine the bandwidth of wireless and wired NICs?
My server (using Ubuntu server 22.04 LTS) has a 100M wireless and wired network card, and I'm using it to run a website (pure IPv6).
Both NICs are currently connected to the same router, is it possible to combine their bandwidth?
Before this, I tried bonding and mptcp, but they both failed. There is very little information about them on the Internet, and each article says something different. Most of them only mention ipv4.
What I want to confirm is, is it due to my operating error, or is it simply impossible?
This is the current status of my NIC:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:58:7b:14:55:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.3.234/24 metric 100 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global dynamic enp2s0
       valid_lft 48772sec preferred_lft 48772sec
    inet6 2409:****:****:****:****:****:****:****/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 5527sec preferred_lft 1927sec
    inet6 2409:****:****:****:****:****:****:****/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 6842sec preferred_lft 3242sec
    inet6 fe80::67d:7bff:feb8:55a2/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 20:63:9d:4f:96:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.3.233/24 metric 600 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global dynamic wlp3s0
       valid_lft 48770sec preferred_lft 48770sec
    inet6 2409:****:****:****:****:****:****:****/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 7077sec preferred_lft 3477sec
    inet6 2409:****:****:****:****:****:****:****/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 6842sec preferred_lft 3242sec
    inet6 fe80::2268:9dff:fe31:c655/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

My English is not good, so I use Google Translate, sorry.

Even if this was possible could the router handle it?

@David Because the server is at my home and I'm using a home router, it doesn't seem to be able to do those more "advanced" operations :(

Seems you have answered your own question.

@David I was wondering if it is possible to handle this situation with just the server.

Bonding requires configuration on both ends, so it won't work if your router doesn't support configuring it.  And typically bonding for bandwidth requires identical interfaces.  You'd have better luck with multiple stream file transfer clients, but that won't work for a web server.
